# flutter & google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, searchbar

Below is my code. I have implemented search bar for address, but it doesn't shown. More important in the functionality is, that google map will show the address, given from a customer.
Maybe I need a function which converts address (street, nr, postal code, city) into LatLong. I have tried with geolocator plugin, but find only reversed solutions -> LatLong into Address.

So my customer gives his address and I need google map to show me this address on the map.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:material_floating_search_bar/material_floating_search_bar.dart';

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  MapsDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Maps Demo";

  @override
  MapsDemoState createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  static final CameraPosition _position1 = CameraPosition(
    bearing: 192.833,
    target: LatLng(45.531563, -122.677433),
    tilt: 59.440,
    zoom: 11.0,
  );

  Future<void> _goToPosition1() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_position1));
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  /*_onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
          position: _lastMapPosition,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'This is a Title',
            snippet: 'This is a snippet',
          ),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
*/
  Widget buildFloatingSearchBar() {
    final isPortrait =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;

    return FloatingSearchBar(
      hint: 'Search...',
      scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 56),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      axisAlignment: isPortrait ? 0.0 : -0.1,
      openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
      width: isPortrait ? 600 : 500,
      debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      onQueryChanged: (query) {},
      // Specify a custom transition to be used for
      // animating between opened and closed stated.
      transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
      actions: [
        FloatingSearchBarAction(
          showIfOpened: false,
          child: CircularButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.place),
            onPressed: () {
              _goToPosition1();
            },
          ),
        ),
        FloatingSearchBarAction.searchToClear(
          showIfClosed: false,
        ),
      ],
      builder: (context, transition) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: Colors.accents.map((color) {
                return Container(height: 112, color: color);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Kundenlocation'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _center,
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              markers: _markers,
              onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //button(_onMapTypeButtonPressed, Icons.map),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    //button(_onAddMarkerButtonPressed, Icons.add_location),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    ),
                    //button(_goToPosition1, Icons.location_searching),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need something like `Google places API` and `reverse geocoding`.

Comment: isnt is forward geocoding? with given address convert to LatLong? What do you mean with Google Places API?

Comment: There's a google places API, that you give it text, for example name of hotel, and it gives you the address and LatLng

Comment: [Look here](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing).

Comment: You can use the [google_maps_webservice](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) package which will allow you to send Geocoding API requests that converts street addresses into LatLng values.

Comment: You may also check the [example](https://github.com/lejard-h/google_maps_webservice/blob/master/test/geocoding_test.dart) here from the same package.